# Is it something wrong with this build or it is ok?

Tags: iphone, installation, adhoc

Now I want to test it to iPhone that is  on  a different location .
I am sending the .mobileprovision certificate , the xcode adhoc build and a private key . but at that end the application installation failed in between 
.
I have doubt that I have something wrong with my build as I am getting the following build image on my build myapp.app . So it is something wrong with my build or its ok ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `no` symbol is stating that it cant be run on that platform (i.e. your desktop). I would imagine that its fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following is assuming you are trying to get the app installed on another iPhone or iPod Touch:

One point: don't send the private key, it is only needed for signing and thus only for development.

All that needs to be sent is the app (usually zip'ed for transmittal) and the Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile.  The provisioning file needs to contain the device ID of the phone it will be installed on.

Recipients of the application will need to drag the application file and Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile into iTunes, then sync their iPhone to iTunes to install.

Comment: but what about the build image is it ok ?